# Codeigniter doesnt load the model

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a controller class and inside i have a contructor, that loads a specific model. I've checked the model code, theres not anything wrong in it. However the controller script shows a white screen error if that model is loaded.
Heres the controller code:

```
class Home extends CI_Controller
{
     function __construct()
     {
          parent::__construct();
          $this->load->model('Adder');
     }

     public function send_feedback()
     {
          $this->Adder->addTo('feedback');
     }
 }
```

Comment: Do you have a file named `Adder.php` inside `application/models` ? Does that file starts with `class Adder extends CI_Model` ?

Comment: Yes it does. Thanx for the reply, i've solved it. Was a minor typo in my controller

Comment: If this no longer seems like a useful question, you might consider deleting it. Otherwise, you could post an answer (or perhaps AdrienXL could post his) and then accept it.

Comment: Im not able to delete the question